# Изменение текста в ListView при нажатии

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Хочу изменить текст элемента списка (ListView). Элемент формируется динамически в адаптере.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(Title[position]);
        textView.setTextSize(30);
        return textView;
    }
```

В обработчике хочу при нажатии на элемент изменить его текст

Пытаюсь сделать так но не получается

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
    ((TextView)view.findFocus()).setText("asdasdasda");

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить ету проблему. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возвращать в getView адаптера каждый раз новый view - это очень-очень плохо. Используйте параметр convertView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно установить обработчик setOnItemClickListener():

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
        TextView txtView = (TextView)view;
        txtView.setText("blah blah blah"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cписок из каких view состоит? Если тупо TextView, то тоже самое что у вас, только без .findFocus(), если кастомная вьюха - реализуйте метод смены текста.